# Accessing Angular scope variable from non-angular javascript function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a list of values in $scope from a controller. Need to access those in a non-angular javascript function.

I have a route like:

```
.when("/display", {
            templateUrl: "html/display.html",
            controller: "DisplayController"
        })
```

In display.html, I have the following javascript function. I have number of them, in fact

```
<script>
  var g = new JustGage({
    id: "gauge",
    value: 67,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    title: "Visitors"
  });
</script>
```

In above function, value need to be passed from a list variable in $scope from  angular DisplayController.

How do I do it? How do I specify the values which are in $scope.list?

I have seen other questions in similar lines.. Proposed solution are like doing something like

```
angular.element(myDomElement).scope()
```

I am using ng-view and not actually specifying any controller in any of the elements. In this case, is it ng-view element?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you try var v=angular.element("#id").scope() , then i think you can use list as v.list inside your javascript function

Comment: #id.. Not clear which id to be considered. I am using ng-view and route binds html and controller.

Comment: Can you please create jsfiddle for above question.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just instantiate JustGage in your controller and add it to the scope?

Comment: Or be even more Angularly and wrap it in a directive.

Comment: Or what Andy said. You should always think directives or filters in most cases.

Comment: Good question, but it should have been a comment. It is not answering the asked question

Comment: Sometimes, a question can be an answer. In this case a prompt I'll admit.

Comment: This gauge expects a div element of id ( for example in the sample code, id: "gauge")  to exist already on html page. If I am having a list of gauges to be created dynamically on a page, how do I make sure that div elements with  those ids already exist? First the div elements be created and then gauges.

Comment: If you make JustGage a directive, the ID becomes irrelevant. Whenever an instance of JustGage is instantiated its, compile, link and controller functions will be called, rather than you having to search for the instances by ID.